# Generating A Select With Multiple Nesting

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, recursion

I have multiple nested product categories and I need these in a select box for selection in my admin system.I am using the following function to generate a multidimensional array which can then be passed to codeigniter's [form_dropdown function](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html). This will accept an array within an array, but not a further array inside. If the item in the top level of an array is an array, it will generate an optgroup element instead of a select option. Look at this code for a further explaination:

```
$categories = array(
    0 => "top level 1",                 //Generates an <option> element correctly
    "sub level name" => array (         //Generates an <optgroup> element correctly
        2 => "sub level 1",
        "sub sub level name" = array(   //Generates <option value="sub sub level name">Array</option>
            3 => "sub sub level 1"
        )
    )
);
```

To avoid the sub sub level generating an incorrect option element, I need it to generate a sub level with 4 &nbsp's before it, like so:

```
     $categories = array(
        0 => "top level 1",                 //Generates an <option> element correctly
        "sub level name" => array (         //Generates an <optgroup> element correctly
            2 => "sub level 1"
        ),
       "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;sub sub level name" = array(    //Generates an <optgroup> element correctly
                3 => "sub sub level 1"      //Generates an <option> element correctly
            )
    );
```

I can't work out how to do this. I think my code is 95% of the way there as it will generate the first code snippet, but I cannot get to the second code snippet. Here is my function:

```
function createCategoryOptions($categories, $spacing = "", $top = true)
{
    print_r($categories);
    $options = array();
    foreach ($categories as $key=>&$category) 
    {
        if (array_key_exists('children', $category))
        {
            usort($category['children'], function($a, $b) {
                return count($b) - count($a);
            } );
            if($top)
            {
                $options[$spacing.$category['product_category_title']] = createCategoryOptions($category['children'], $spacing."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", false);
            }
            else
            {
                //This is what generates sub sub levels incorrectly
                $options[$spacing.$category['product_category_title']] = createCategoryOptions($category['children'], $spacing."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $options[$key] = $spacing.$category['product_category_title'];
        }
    }

    return $options;
}
```

And here is some sample data which gets input into the function:

```
array
(
    //Top Level
    [14] => array
        (
            [product_category_id] => 14
            [product_category_parent_id] => 
            [product_category_title] => Daily Living
            [children] => array
                (
                    //Sub Level
                    [58] => array
                        (
                            [product_category_id] => 58
                            [product_category_parent_id] => 14
                            [product_category_title] => Daily Living : AJ Way
                            [children] => array
                                (
                                    //Sub Sub level
                                    [68] => array
                                        (
                                            [product_category_id] => 68
                                            [product_category_parent_id] => 58
                                            [product_category_title] => Daily Living : AJ Way : Coverdry
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `optgroup` tag:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="German Cars">
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

also, you need a recurrence there.

Comment: I am attempting to use optgroups,  see the comments in the top 2 code snippets

Comment: you need a function generateOptions($array){} that inserts the options and when it reaches 'children' calls  generateOptions($array['children']) ...

Comment: Isn't that what the function in the third snippet does or is it different?